# AVPlayer stop UIActivityIndicator before playing

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avplayer

I'm trying to stop activityIndicator when AVPlayer start playing music, and also start activityIndicator when again AVPlayer start (loading, buffering). It little bit works, the problem is that AVPlayer stop activityIndicator before some seconds (5,6,7) before playing music. And also it not start again activityIndicator when it again (loading, buffering). Any one have any idea where is my mistake or what i need to fix it. Thanks

```
var activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .WhiteLarge)

var selectIndex:Int = -1

var check = true
var url : String!
var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
var player:AVPlayer?

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RadioCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    let object = objects[indexPath.row]
    cell.img.image = UIImage(named: object["image"]!)
    cell.btnPlay.addTarget(self, action: Selector("audioControlButtonAction:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.btnPlay.tag = indexPath.row+1


    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}

func audioControlButtonAction(sender: UIButton){

    if check == false {
        deallocObservers(player!)
    }



    var btn:NSInteger
    btn = sender.tag as NSInteger

    let object = objects[btn-1]
    let nurl = NSURL(string: "\(object["url"]!)")!
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: nurl)
    player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)

    print(selectIndex)
    if selectIndex != -1 && selectIndex != sender.tag
    {
        let bt:UIButton = self.view.viewWithTag(selectIndex) as! UIButton

        if bt.selected == true
        {
            bt.selected = false
        }
    }

    if sender.selected == false{
        player!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
        player!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
        player!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
        player!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options:NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
        player!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
        player!.play()
        sender.selected = true
        check = false
        selectIndex = sender.tag
        activityView.startAnimating()


    }
    else{
        activityView.stopAnimating()
        check = true
        player?.pause()
        sender.selected = false
        selectIndex = -1
    }

    print(selectIndex)

}

func deallocObservers(player: AVPlayer) {

    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty")
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp")
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loadedTimeRanges")
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull")

}


override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>){

    if object?.isEqual(player) == true && keyPath == "status" {

        print(player?.status)

        switch player!.status {

            case AVPlayerStatus.Failed:
                print("Player item status failed")
                player?.play()
            break

            case AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay:
                print("Player item status is ready to play")
                activityView.stopAnimating()
            break

            case AVPlayerStatus.Unknown:
                print("player item status is unknown")
            break
        }

        switch keyPath! {

            case "playbackBufferFull":
                activityView.stopAnimating()
                print("playbackBufferFull")
            break

            case "playbackLikelyToKeepUp":
                activityView.stopAnimating()
                print("playbackLikelyToKeepUp")
            break

            case "playbackBufferEmpty":
                activityView.startAnimating()
                print("playbackBufferEmpty")
            break

            case "loadedTimeRanges":
                print("loadedTimeRanges")

            default:
                print("Error")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

}

> **Output**

AVPlayer start playing after(5,6,7 seconds) this line `Player item status is ready to play`

```
-1
1
Optional(__C.AVPlayerStatus)
Player item status is ready to play
Error
1
-1
-1
1
Optional(__C.AVPlayerStatus)
Player item status is ready to play
Error
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well in your code, whenever a cell is pressed you have `activityView.stopAnimating()`. so no matter what, either the animation will start OR stop on click, depending `if sender.selected == false`

So I think if you remove `activityView.stopAnimating()` then it will not stop animating so early. It's kind of hard to read your question and code as I am not sure exactly where the output is coming from.

Comment: First time when i pressed on play button just that code execute `if sender.selected == false{............}`  on `audioControlButtonAction` button?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding second problem i.e. "And also it not start again activityIndicator when it again (loading, buffering)"

I think a workaround for that could be one of following:-

a)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
//Start activityView Animation when user clicks on any item which won't be buffered by default
activityView.startAnimating()
}
```

or

b)

```
var selectIndex:Int = -1 {
didSet {
      //Start activityView Animation when user clicks on any item which won't be buffered by default
      activityView.startAnimating()
       }
}
```

Comment: No i mean first time it show activityIndicator also stop activityIndicator when play music but when next time it needs to buffer or load again due to slow internet connection or due to another reason it not start `startAnimating`.

Comment: I think the problem is in `observeValueForKeyPath` becauase it always just goes in `AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay` or in `default:`?

Comment: maybe i am not so sure, add breakpoints and see how the execution goes to confirm whether the issue is with observerValueForKeyPath or something else. Also if its due to slower connections include Reachability to check connection availability